# Making a local address on network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

I'm planning on making a .home "site" on my network. I've noticed certain devices such as the WD MyBookLive have a local configuration page at *mybooklive.local* that is accessible from any computer on the network even if it is not present in /etc/hosts.

Ex) A new phone joins my network and goes to *coolwebsite.home* and it goes to an html file on one of my computers.

Is there any way to have a local domain name that is accessible from any computer on the network without modifying /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you asked - you would require to run a comined hybrid and authorative DNS server. Some better routers will do this seemlessly - you can assign an IP address to a MAC address. ( dd-wrt can do this).

Another solution which doesn't meet the "all computers" requirement would be to enable WINS - Windows Nameserver - which is related to Windows filesharing.

A third way - which I mention for completeness - would be to purchase a domain name, set up the subdomain in the DNS, then ensure the domain name is correctly set for each system, and the appropriate mac-> IP address is done in DHCP or static IP address in is used.

Comment: Apple's Bonjour service would be the equivalent of WINS.